# Is it possible to fix a jumbotron and nav bar to the top of a screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm building my site with Bootstrap and I want to keep my header and nav bar at the top of my page as the rest of the content scrolls under it. I know you can fix a navbar to the top with Bootstrap, but is there a way to fix the jumbotron to the top as well?

My current code is:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <img class="jumbotron-img-top" src="images/headerwithtag.png">
    </div>

  <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      BOOKS
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

and the css with is is:

```
.jumbotron {
          background-color: white;
      }

      .jumbotron-img-top {
          width:100%;
      }

      .navbar {
          background-image: url("images/navbarbgnew.png");
          background-size: cover;
          margin: -30px 0 15px 0;
      }
```

I'm just not sure what I need in order to fix both things to the top while still filling the entire screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way -- using *only **Bootstrap 4** native classes* without any custom css -- to fix both, the jumbotron and the navbar to the top of the screen, is to wrap them both in a div with the class `sticky-top` like so (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page to check):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="sticky-top">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-white my-0 py-0">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/200">
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    BOOKS
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium fugit veritatis ipsam possimus iste ipsum aut cupiditate earum eveniet vel minus laudantium eligendi, et blanditiis tempore itaque enim facere dolorum deserunt obcaecati autem? <br><br> Dolorem earum enim est, voluptas harum eveniet pariatur! Amet, ipsum necessitatibus explicabo repellat quisquam, eum nam, cupiditate excepturi sed magni, natus commodi deserunt cum praesentium provident debitis dolore ducimus expedita totam non. A sed praesentium dolorum doloremque ipsa nesciunt quis inventore fugiat voluptatum, deleniti, rem. <br><br> Animi iure obcaecati fuga repellendus porro repellat et necessitatibus maiores, explicabo veniam totam molestiae dolorem deleniti, accusamus aperiam vitae. Provident, sapiente! Facere labore explicabo illo incidunt quas laborum placeat sunt perspiciatis suscipit ducimus esse distinctio molestiae expedita ipsam animi iste delectus id, cum est possimus quos eveniet similique necessitatibus. Tempora itaque impedit aperiam asperiores ullam qui, non explicabo dignissimos odio dicta ipsam molestias officia libero porro aliquid quod deleniti magni tempore similique magnam amet sapiente. <br><br> Laboriosam consectetur suscipit voluptatem, debitis, minus repellat iure cum odio illum explicabo deleniti. Repellat ad et quaerat, fuga quis iste a autem illo repellendus iusto ipsum nesciunt eius fugit, repudiandae, voluptates? Alias voluptate reiciendis esse libero sed debitis deserunt totam, repellat. Iusto soluta, corporis animi nesciunt optio corrupti non aut ad magnam beatae illo voluptatibus iste quidem numquam impedit reiciendis similique nihil omnis odio quod? Molestiae repellendus atque, adipisci.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much! Almost everything looks great now- but this seems to have broken the dropdown tab. Nothing happens when it is clicked. Any suggestions?

Comment: It was just because I forgot to add the JavaScript links. Check my updated code snippet now. And click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `position: fixed` to the .jumbotron class, then set `top: 0` to get the element fixed to the very top of the browser viewport. I would set a `width:100%` as the position:fixed will shrink your element.

```
  .jumbotron {
      background-color: white;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

```css
.jumbotron {
          background-color: white;
          position: fixed;
          width: 100%;
          top: 0;
      }

      .jumbotron-img-top {
          width:100%;
      }

      .navbar {
          background-image: url("images/navbarbgnew.png");
          background-size: cover;
          margin: -30px 0 15px 0;
      }
      .long-content-sample {
          height: 1000px;
          background: #ccc;
      }
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
      <img class="jumbotron-img-top" src="images/headerwithtag.png">
      .jumbotron element
    </div>

  <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      BOOKS
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="long-content-sample">Scroll down<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed;` or `position: sticky` to the DOM node which you have to position in a fixed manner.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position